# Simple Python 3 regex query

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Trying to learn regex I have created a simple string:

words = "qwe854345 bvc7321 kjd865"

I want to write a regex that will find:
qwe854345 bvc7321 kjd865

So I tried the following:

```
import re
words = "qwe854345 bvc7321 kjd865"
results = re.findall(r'(qwe|bvc|kjd)+\w+')
```

My thinking was: I want qwe OR/AND bvc OR/AND kjd followed by the numbers, so I used \w to get the following alphanumerical characters. Of course it didn't work. All I'm getting is qwe bvc kjd. I have found a way around by trying:
results = re.findall('qwe+\w+|bvc+\w+|kjd+\w+')

I have read the HOWTO on docs.python.org (several times) and watched 2 regex tutorials on YT. Still, I can't understand why the first attempt didn't work. Can anyone please explain that to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `()` (capturing group) `re.findall` will return only capturing groups. `(?:)` Non capturing group should be used instead .

**Regex**: [`(?:qwe|bvc|kjd)\d+`](http://regex101.com/r/ERk8Ik/1)

Details:

- `(?:)` Non capturing group
- `|` Or
- `\d` Matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

**Python code**:

```
def get(text):
    return re.findall(r"(?:qwe|bvc|kjd)\d+", text)

get('qwe854345 bvc7321 kjd865') >> ['qwe854345', 'bvc7321', 'kjd865']
```

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for prompt help. The code provided really helped me to understand the problem and I think I start to understand where and when to use non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
(?:qwe|bvc|kjd)\d+
```

`\w` is for alphabet words. `\d` is for numbers.
and you don't need a plus in `(qwe|bvc|kjd)+` unless you want to cover two of them combined like "qwebvc" too. Finally, you should use `(?:qwe|bvc|kjd)` instead `(qwe|bvc|kjd)` if you are not using back reference.